# Qt installed in two places; wrong one takes precedence

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, debian-installer, qt, qtcreator

My system is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I seem to have installed Qt in two places. 4.8.7 is installed in `/usr` and 5.5.1 is installed in my home directory for reasons which probably seemed sensible at the time.

```
$ /usr/bin/qmake -v
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

$ ~/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/bin/qmake -v
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.5.1 in /home/jsd/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/lib

$ which qmake
/usr/bin/qmake
```

Qt Creator sees the home-directory version and thinks it's running 5.5.1, but when it runs `qmake` in the build process it runs the 4.8.7 version and minor annoyances follow.

How can I clean this up? Also, is it normal for Qt to be installed in my home directory?

**Edit:** The reason this was an issue is Qt Creator was ignoring `CONFIG += c++14` and refusing to allow C++14 syntax like `auto foo = [](const a, const b){return a<b;};` when compiling with Clang 3.7, which should support C++14. `qmake` only supported `CONFIG += c++14` since 5.4 hence I thought the problem was my old `qmake` version.

Comment: It's only normal if you are doing QT development.

Comment: @jordanm As in working on building the Qt framework? I'm not doing that, I just use Qt to write programs in a dabbling way.

Comment: Can you delete (or rename) the `qmake` in your home directory and then create a symlink there pointing to `/usr/bin/qmake`? Or the other way around depending on which version you wish to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt5 was installed in your local directory because you didn't install it as root or admin.

wherever you set your path, .bashrc, .cshrc, .zshrc, .profile etc, the system files have taken precedence over your files.

modify your PATH, so that the system finds your local copy of QT5 first.

`export PATH=$USER/Qt:${PATH}`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

- remove Qt4 via the package manager
- install Qt5 via the package manager
- delete Qt from the home folder
- qtcreator *still* ignores `CONFIG += C++14` when compiling with Clang (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻
- Edit `usr/lib/x64_84-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/features/c++14.prf` and comment out the guards intended to only apply `-std=c++1y` to Clang 3.2 and higher (which seem to be applying despite only having Clang 3.7 installed)

Modified `c++14.prf` file:

```
intel_icc {
    # ICC does not support C++14 yet
} else: clang {

#    # Clang has supported -std=c++1y since version 3.2
#    greaterThan(QT_CLANG_MAJOR_VERSION, 3)|greaterThan(QT_CLANG_MINOR_VERSION, 1): \

        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++14

#    # Unknown how long Apple Clang has supported -std=c++1y, but at least since XCode 5.0
#    greaterThan(QT_APPLE_CLANG_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): \
#        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++1y

} else: gcc {
    # GCC has supported -std=c++1y since 4.8
    greaterThan(QT_GCC_MAJOR_VERSION, 4)|greaterThan(QT_GCC_MINOR_VERSION, 7): \
        QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_CXX11 = -std=c++1y
}

# Delegate to c++11.prf
include(c++11.prf)
```